# Raspberry PI Kiosk does not detect plugged in display

Tags: linux, debian, xorg, raspberry-pi, openbox

I have many Raspberry PIs setup as Kiosks.  I install Raspberry Lite Debian version, then install openbox and use autostart script to run chromium.  It all works great "if" the display is plugged in and on when the PI starts up.  If the display is turned on after the PI is already on the PI does NOT automatically connect to it.  Is there a Linux package I need to install to auto connect to display?  Or maybe a udev script?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simple solution.  On the Raspberry PI you can edit options in /boot/config.txt

```
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
```

This will enable hot plugging HDMI but this only detects 656 x 416 resolution which can be fixed with:

```
hdmi_group=1
hdmi_mode=16
```

Available modes are available here :

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/video.md

The only drawback is that this forces the video mode to one mode so if you swap the TV/monitor and the new display does not support the video mode you will have troubles changing it.